# Kotlin 1.6, Jetpack Compose 1.1.0 compilation error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have updated my project to Kotlin 1.6.10, Compose 1.1.0-rc01 and compose compiler to 1.1.0-rc02, because I need some new features in Compose.

During compilation I have now this error, any solution ?
It was working with Kotlin 1.5.31, Compose/Compose compiler 1.0.5

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Symbol for kotlin.collections/mutableMapOf|-4813910536206556932[0] is unbound
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrBindablePublicSymbolBase.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrSimpleFunctionPublicSymbolImpl.getOwner(IrPublicSymbolBase.kt:74)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitCall(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:663)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:46)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:114)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:115)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpressionBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.accept(IrBody.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpressionBody.transform(IrBody.kt:39)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.transformChildren(IrField.kt:41)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:82)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitField(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrField.accept(IrField.kt:34)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:66)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitClass$s780614737(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:466)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:465)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:194)
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitClass(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:465)

etc.....```
````

Comment: If you have a minimal repro for this please submit a bug at https://goo.gle/compose-feedback

Comment: Here is the ticket with that issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/211475860

Comment: Now tracking on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50784

Comment: kotlin 1.6.20 has a fix for this, once released that will be the answer to update kotlin and the jetpack compose to 1.6.20+ based versions

Answer (score 37):

I encountered the exact same issue on two different projects when updating the Compose & Kotlin versions.

Removing the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin resolved the issue on both projects for me. This means you can no longer use Kotlin synthetics for view binding.

Comment: This is the right answer, caused due to that plugin deprecation

Comment: so i cannnot use compose in an app already built with conventional view based android ?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Yes, you can! But you can not use kotlin synthetics which means you should use either view binding or findviewbyid.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen a few other reports (and myself) seeing the same thing.  One temporary workaround is to use new compose with an older compose compiler that doesn't force you to upgrade kotlin since you only need the new compose functionality.  Add something like this in your build.gradle with a similar compose version that supports your kotlin version (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

```
composeOptions {    
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = '1.1.0-beta03'
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a newer version of the downgraded compiler?

The compile error at the start of the thread is a bug in kotlin 1.6.0 and 1.6.10, this sets only the compose compiler to use an older kotlin version to workaround it.  Setting it to a newer version makes you hit the bug so I don't know why you'd want to set it to a newer version.

Answer (score 3):

This issue arises when you use both Jetpack Compose & kotlin synthetic bindings on the same project.
Removing the `kotlin-android-extensions` (used for synthetic binding) plugin will resolve the issue.
**Also, synthetic binding is now deprecated you should migrate the code to view binding.**
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

But this was not possible for me at this moment which will require at least 5-6 days for me to do so as I have around 50-60 files using this.
So I have to choose the other way around for this case,

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.1.0-beta03"
}
```

I also have to downgrade the Kotlin version for this.

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
ext.compose_version = '1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Kotlin version fixed my problem. While upgrading, please check  the Compose-Kotlin compatibility check mentioned in the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)

I have upgraded to Kolin : `1.6.20` and used `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0-alpha08"`. This is an older Kotlin version, you can try the latest one.

Answer (score -1):

Use below versions to fix the problem
composeOptions {
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.0-beta03'
kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.31'
}